# extract specific part of html code

Tags: java, html, extract

I am doing my first Android app and I have to take the code of a html page.

Actually I am doing this:

```
    private class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String > {
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL oracle = new URL("http://www.nationalleague.ch/NL/fr/");
            URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            String s1 = "";
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                s1 = s1 + inputLine;
            in.close();


            //return
            return s1;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

but the problem is it takes too much time. How to take for exemple the HTML from the line 200 to the line 300 ?

Sorry for my bad english :$

Comment: @user1965878: Much better

Comment: Cool, that's going to help everybody including you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best case use instead of `readLine()` use `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)`. Another dirty way

```
int i =0;
while(while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
i++;
if(i>200 || i<300 )
DO SOMETHING
in.close();)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the HTML document through HTTP. HTTP usually relies on TCP. So... you can't just "skip lines"! The server will always try to send you all data preceding the portion of your interest, and your side of communication must acknowledge the reception of such data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not read line by line      [use `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len`)]
2. Do not concat Strings         [use a `StringBuilder`]

Open The buffered reader (much like you already do):

```
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.nationalleague.ch/NL/fr/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
```

Instead of reading line by line, read in a `char[]` (I would use one of size about 8192)
and than use a `StringBuilder` to append all the read `char`s.

Reading secific lines of HTML-source seams a little risky because formatting of the source code of the HTML page may change.